# Display the photos as on Google+

Tags: google-plus, photo-gallery

I'm currently working on a gallery to my photos. Besides some bugs, I'm finished with the gallery but I want to add a new and fresh theme to the front page. I'm very in love with [how Google+ shows the photos](https://plus.google.com/photos/108346685434991182200/albums/5712493045931432833) and I'm asking you now, how can I add this effect for my list of photos in my own gallery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears they are using `div`s for rows and sub-`div`s for columns. You could, dynamically or statically, determine which of these formats you will have for the row:

```
//1
[    ][  ]
[    ][  ]
[    ]====
[    ][  ]
//2
[   ][   ]
[   ][   ]
```

From there style the rows and columns as `{ float: left }` and make images `{ width: 100% }`. Here is a tutorial on infinite scrolling image galleries: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-web-gallery/ and you could just `fade in` images as you display them.

Comment: Thanks for the basic information about how I can accomplish this :)